# Self-generated SSL Certificate Not Working with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, https

I've tried to follow a tutorial on self-generating a SSL Certificate.  I've created a file "www.mysite.com.csr" and a file "www.mysite.com.key".  However, when I restart apache, it doesn't prompt me for the passphrase, as the tutorial suggests.

I also tried to configure my virtual hosts to rewrite to https and it failed.

Do I have to make a change to the httpd config file to make my certificate work?

Here is my virtual host conf:

```
   <IfDefine SSL> 
   <VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /home/project/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/lib/ssl/www.mysite.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/lib/ssl/www.msyite.com.key

    #SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

  </VirtualHost>
 </IfDefine>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post a copy of your configuration files here (The relevant parts in httpd, or if you are using ubuntu/debian the correct virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled). Without that information it is very hard to figure out whats going on.

Are you sure that you actually told the virtual host (or httpd.conf) file to use the SSL cert? If apache does not know that the key exists it wont do anything with it. 
You need to have something like this in a VirtualHost

```
SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www.mysite.csr
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /path/to/www.mysite.key
```

Are you sure that you set a password on your SSL key?
Are you sure you have enabled SSL for apache, and have port 443 running?

Comment: I did set a password on my SSL key.  I'm not sure if I have port 443 running outside of trying http:mysite.com in my brower

Comment: http will normally go to port 80, try going to https://

go to http://blogs.sitepoint.com/securing-apache-2-server-ssl/, there are two parts in there which talk about enabling SSL(LoadModule part) and the 2nd is a sample virtualhost config

Comment: right, so i followed a similar tutorial. I'm stuck. apache is telling me that SSLEngine module is not included in the server configuration

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, try this:
httpd stop
httpd startssl
httpd restart
from http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/SSL-RedHat-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.3

Comment: hurray! I sort of have it now.  After your wonderful suggestion about a2, I googled that term and came across a great tutorial.  I made some changes and I now have SSL working. Thanks so much Pratik!

Comment: My only remaining issue is that I receive a warning: _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443.  As instructed in ports.conf, I changed the <VirtualHost _default_:443> declaration in the default-ssl file to <VirtualHost *:443>. It's still claiming that _default_ exists...

Comment: Are you using redhat(fedora,centos) or Debian(ubuntu)

Comment: I'm using Debian

Comment: Look inside of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/, there should be a few files in there (default and default-ssl), look through all of them and make sure that you dont have any overlapping virtual hosts. all your VirtualHost config should be inside there

Comment: right, I thought the same. I have *:443 virtual host listed in both default and default-ssl.  I was going to comment out default-ssl, but I was afraid it would screw things up.  Should I just comment it all out?

Comment: yeah comment out one of them (probably default)

Comment: perfect, I actually commented out default-ssl. I wanted to keep my :80 and :443 configurations in one spot, so I left default in tact.  It still worked though.  Thanks for all your help Pratik